# How do I (or should I?) access the service layer from a SiteMesh template (views/layouts/main.gsp) in Grails?

Tags: grails

I need to create a toplist in the page footer on a site that I'm building. The footer is created in the default SiteMesh layout template (`views/layouts/main.gsp`).

In order to create the toplist access to the database is needed, so I've encapsulated all logic needed for the toplist creation in a service class (`services/FooService`).

Please note that while services are usually accessed from the controller layer, in this case the default layout template (`views/layouts/main.gsp`) is **not** generated from a controller.

- Can the layout view (`views/layouts/main.gsp`) access a service class? How?
- Is this the correct design decision? If not, what is a better encapsulation and how do I interact with said encapsulation from the layout view (`views/layouts/main.gsp`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest creating a tag library ([documented here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.3%20Tag%20Libraries)) to wrap the rendering of your footer. You can inject your service into the tag library class by simply declaring a field with the same name.

Then get what you need from the service and either output the html directly or better yet create a `_footer.gsp` and [render it](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) with `render template: 'footer', model: [yourmodel: model]`.

Comment: Can the tag lib be used from the SiteMesh layout template (in this case views/layouts/main.gsp)?

Comment: Sure - tags are designed to be used from within templates. They're your version of doing (for example) `<g:checkBox ... />`

Comment: And cache the output of the tagLib call

Answer (score 0):

You should access your service from your controllers instead of the views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not solve my problem since the default template (views/layouts/main.gsp) is not rendered from a controller.