# Grails: Access to model in main.gsp layout

Tags: grails, groovy

I need access to a specific model in my main.gsp layout.  I have searched around and read that the best way to get this is to create an after filter and apply the model to the viewModel param and then access it in the gsp like so:

```
class MyFilters {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        after = {viewModel ->
            viewModel.client = Client.get(session.clientId)
            // println "Client is: ${client.toString()}"
        }
    }
}
```

And in my GSP, I should get "client" and be able to access it?

```
<g:if test="${client.isPartner()}">
    Do something
</g:if>
<g:else>
    Do something else
</g:else>
```

An example of what I'm trying to do is include GSP templates and include specific CSS stylesheets based on if the current client that is logged in belongs to a partner.  The location of the special CSS and GSP templates depends on the partners name, so for example:

```
<g:if test="${client.isPartner()}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/partners/${client.getPartner().toString()}/css/style.css"/>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/partners/default/css/style.css"/>
</g:else>
```

This would also be done with GSP templates... However, whenever I do this, I get an exception of:

```
ERROR grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet  - Original exception : Cannot invoke method isPartner() on null object
```

So, apparently "client" is null in the GSP. If I uncomment out the println in the after filter shown above, it is not null at this time and the name of the client is printed.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there a better way to get at a model inside of main.gsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of a question I answered recently. I suggested solving this with a tag library:

[How do I (or should I?) access the service layer from a SiteMesh template (views/layouts/main.gsp) in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699259/how-do-i-or-should-i-access-the-service-layer-from-a-sitemesh-template-views/4699408#4699408)

You have access to the session in a tag lib, so a closure a bit like this ought to work:

```
...
static namespace = "yournamespace"
...
def partnerDetails = { attrs, body ->
    def client = Client.get(session.clientId)
    if (client.isPartner()) {
        out << "Whatever you want to write out..."
                    // You can also call other tag libs from here - see docs
    }
    }
...
```

Then you use the tag in your gsp something like this:

```
<yournamespace:partnerDetails />
```

You can also pass attributes in, which are passed into the closure through the `attrs` map, if that's helpful at all.

Finally, if you want to conditionally render the body of the tag, then you can do that like this:

```
...
if (client.isPartner()) {
    out << body()
}
....
```

And you would call it like this:

```
<yournamespace:partnerDetails>
    This is the body content that will be output in the body() call above.
</yournamespace:partnerDetails>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I get a different error about lazy initialization because the isPartner() method accesses a part of the model that is a hasMany relationship.  Not sure why this happens...  However, I would rather just have the client object because there are a few more methods I use from it other than just the isPartner() method. For instance, I need access to the partners as well.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: You really should think about solving this with a taglib. Pulling to much logic into the view violates the MVC concept. Maybe it's easiest if you post the code of the taglib you've tried and people may help..

Comment: Actually, after doing a clean, it works just fine in the taglib.  However, since I really need access to that isPartner() method because I have an if/else to render some CSS based on that condition, and then need the partners ID to get at the CSS in a specific area, would it make sense to have a tag like <mytag:client><g:if test="${client.isPartner()"}>...</g:if><g:else>...</g:else></mytag:client>?  That would give me access to the client object in the body portion of that tag... But is that considered good or bad?

Comment: Actually, I guess that doesn't even work like that.  So, I really need to do an if/else on that isPartner method to either render the CSS for a partner, or render the default CSS if it's not a partner... Not sure how to accomplish that in a taglib.

Comment: Ah - I've also added more detail to my answer at the same time as david! Slightly different solution. See which you prefer.

Comment: I think both ideas are on target, but this doesn't handle my "else" conditional. I'm trying to include CSS and also a couple of custom GSP templates based on if the current client that is logged in is part of a partner group. If they aren't, then a default CSS and GSP template is shown in the main layout. I guess I could hide it all in a taglib and make a bunch of tags based on each item I may need to include, but that seems to me like a lot of redundant code in some cases (especially calls out to the database to get the client each time). I updated my post to show an example.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the version with the body described above, then - rendering your template or css include when approriate. Call is `isPartner`, as described by david. Can't see what would be redundant - you're just checking the condition each time. No need to worry about multiple calls the database, as GORM is abstracting that problem away - you'll get the object back from the Hibernate cache on subsequent calls.

Comment: The resources plugin may also be of interest for bundling your css & javascript: http://grails.org/plugin/resources

Comment: Any reason why this would cause an issue when grails throws a 404 error?  I get lazy initialization exceptions when something is does not exist and grails throws a 404 and my custom 404 error page is rendered. The taglib gets the client with no problem, but when isPartner() is called, it throws a lazy initialization exception...

Answer (score 1):

That filter will only match requests that go through a controller.  If you are routing directly to a view in UrlMappings.groovy, it won't get hit.  Try something like this to filter urls regardless of whether they route through a controller.

```
class MyFilters {
    all(uri: "/**") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either... I get the same error. However, it is indeed going through a controller for the page I'm testing it on. I just need it available for all pages since it needs to be in main.gsp.

Comment: Could be a namespacing issue.  Does `${pageScope.getProperty('client')}` evaluate to anything in the GSP?

Comment: Oddly enough, if I print out that in my GSP, I get the toString() of the client object.  Which is what I'd expect. However, I also get this exception:  Error evaluating expression [pageScope.getProperty('client')] on line [5]: No such property: client for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageBinding

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating following TagLib:

```
<g:ifPartner id="123">This client is a partner</g:ifPartner>
```

The corresponding code would look something like this:

```
def isPartner = { attrs, body ->

  def id = attrs.remove('id')
  if (Client.get(id)?.isPartner()) {
    out << body()
  }
}
```